# How to shift the eigenvalues of a quantum Hermitian operator G to ±r?

Tags: quantum-gate

Consider a gate $\mathcal{G}(\mu)=e^{-i \mu G}$ generated by a Hermitian operator G. If G has just two distinct eigenvalues(which can be repeated) we can, without loss of generality,
shift the eigenvalues to ±r, as the global phase is unobservable. Note that any single qubit gate is of this form.

I dont know **How to shift the eigenvalues of a quantum Hermitian operator G to ±r ?**

[Schuld, Maria, et al. "Evaluating analytic gradients on quantum hardware." Physical Review A 99.3 (2019): 032331.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.11184)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Consider a gate $\mathcal{G}(\mu)=e^{-i \mu G}$ generated by a Hermitian operator G. If G has just two distinct eigenvalues(which can be repeated) we can, without loss of generality,
> shift the eigenvalues to ±r, as the global phase is unobservable. Note that any single qubit gate is of this form.
>
> I dont know **How to shift the eigenvalues of a quantum Hermitian operator G to ±r ?**

Let the distinct eigenvalues of $G$ be denoted as $g_1$ and $g_2$.

Consider the Hermitian operator $\tilde G$, defined as:
$$
\tilde G \equiv G - \frac{1}{2}\left(g_1 + g_2\right)\mathbb{I}
$$

The $\tilde G$ operator also has two eigenvalues, which can be denoted as:
$$
r\equiv \frac{1}{2}\left(g_1 - g_2\right)
$$
and
$$
-r = \frac{1}{2}\left(g_2 - g_1\right)
$$

---

So we can write $\mathcal{G}$ as:
$$
\mathcal{G}(\mu)=e^{-i \mu G}
=e^{-i \mu (\tilde G + \frac{1}{2}(g_1 + g_2)\mathbb{I})}
$$
$$
=e^{-i\tilde \phi}e^{-i \mu \tilde G}\;,
$$
where $\tilde \phi = \frac{\mu}{2}(g_1 + g_2)$. Note that the final equality above follows because $[\tilde G, \mathbb{I}]=0$, since every operator commutes with the identity operator.

---

More explicitly, we can write, in matrix form, in some basis that diagonalizes $G$ (and $\tilde G$), the result for $\mathcal{G}(\mu)$ as:
$$
\mathcal{G}(\mu) = e^{-i\tilde \phi}
\left(
\begin{matrix} e^{-ir} & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots \\
0 & e^{-ir} & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots \\
0 & 0 & e^{-ir} & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots \\
\ldots &  \ldots &  \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & e^{+ir} & 0 & 0 & \ldots \\
0 &  0 &  0 & \ldots & 0 & e^{+ir} & 0 & \ldots \\
0 &  0 &  0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & e^{+ir} & \ldots \\
\ldots &  \ldots &  \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Say the eigenvalues of $G$ are $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ with $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$. Writing the $2\times 2$ Hermitian matrix $G$ in its eigenbasis (we can pick any basis, since unitary transformations will not affect the spectrum of our operator), we are looking for real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that
\begin{equation}
aG + b = \begin{pmatrix} a\lambda_1 + b & 0 \\ 0 & a \lambda_2 + b \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} r & 0 \\ 0 & -r \end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
This gives a system of equations,
\begin{align}
a \lambda_1 + b &= r \\
a \lambda_2 + b &= -r,
\end{align}
for which you can easily verify the solution is
\begin{align}
a = \frac{2r}{\lambda_1 - \lambda_2}\\
b = -r \frac{(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)}{(\lambda_1 - \lambda_2)}.
\end{align}
Then $aG + b$ has eigenvalues $\pm r$. Physically, this corresponds to running the modified gate
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{G}(\mu) = \exp(i (aG + b) \mu),
\end{equation}
which you can interpret as performing time evolution with respect to $G$ for a factor of $a$ longer (the $b$ introduces physically meaningless global phase, reflecting the fact that we have 'shifted' both of the original energies $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ by some amount but only differences in energies really matter).